# Firefox does not the struts action again on click of browser back button

Tags: firefox, web

I load a page by calling a struts action. Now I go to some other link in the same tab from that page. If I click on browser back button the struts action is not being called again hence I am having some issue with the loading of the page. This behaviour does not exist in chrome as when I click on back button in chrome it calls the struts action again and load the page properly. Any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: It's not the browser issue however it could be a issue with javascript. You have to provide the explanation of the problem with code examples that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: More information is required. Normally when you hit the back button you won't be doing a page reload, it'll be cached.